# JSON serialization with Swift 3

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I am trying to to populate a table by filling an array from JSON data. I am using the code below but keep getting the error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

on the following lines of code:

```
self.tableData.append(jsonResult[i]["title"]! as! String)
self.tableImages.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)
self.tableDesc.append(jsonResult[i]["description"]! as! String)
self.tableValidity.append(jsonResult[i]["validity"]! as! String)
```

My code:

```
 let str3 = Int(str2!)!
            let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.*****.php")!

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                if let urlContent = data {
                    do {

                        let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)


                        print(str3)

                        var i = 0

                        while i < str3 {
                            print(jsonResult[i]["title"]! as!String)
                            print(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)

                            self.tableData.append(jsonResult[i]["title"]! as! String)
                            self.tableImages.append(jsonResult[i]["image"]! as! String)
                            self.tableDesc.append(jsonResult[i]["description"]! as! String)
                            self.tableValidity.append(jsonResult[i]["validity"]! as! String)

                            i = i + 1

                        }

                    } catch {
                        print("JSON serialization failed")
                    }                    

                } else {                    
                    print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
                }                

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                })                                

            }

            task.resume()
```

Comment: Did you see this recent blog entry: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the type of `jsonResult`, you have to tell what it is, for example with optional binding like this:

```
if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as? [[String:AnyObject]] {


}
```

Here I downcast the JSON as an array of dictionaries. Use your loop inside this `if let` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler doesn't know the type the JSON object, you need to cast it to the actual type

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options:[]) as! [[String:Any]]
```

Mutable containers are not needed at all.

The C-`while` loop with incrementing a counter is very ugly. Don't use that in Swift. And you are using too many exclamation marks

```
for item in jsonResult {

  print(item["title"] as! String)
  print(item["image"] as! String)

  self.tableData.append(item["title"] as! String)
  self.tableImages.append(item["image"] as! String)
  self.tableDesc.append(item["description"] as! String)
  self.tableValidity.append(item["validity"] as! String)

}
```

PS: And multiple arrays as data source is also clumsy and error-prone. In an object oriented language a custom struct or class is preferable