# Parsing json having object in (); using swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

How to parse below json response in swift. I want to get the value of "code"

```
jsonResponse : {
messages =     (
            {
        code = "MM_777";
        message = "Password wrong";
    }
);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492440/json-serialization-with-swift-3

Comment: Or use a library like: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: That's not "JSON" anymore, it has already been parsed and transformed into Objective-C/Swift equivalents of Dictionary/Array/String, etc. It's just a Dictionary, with one key ("messages"), and which value is an Array of dictionaries. Simple iterations, etc. Knowing how to iterates/parse dict/array is basic knowledge and important one, but you need to understand how work dict and array first. Is that your case?

Comment: What makes this data JSON in your mind? The `{}` symbols?

Comment: Please give me the code to get value of "code" if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Done it!

```
    if let messages = fromJsonResponse.first {
    let value = messages.value as! Array<AnyObject>
    let dict = value.first as? [String: Any]
    print(dict!["code"] ?? "lax")
}
```